# How to force sudo to use existing kerberos ticket?

Tags: windows-server-2012, centos7, sudo, pam, sssd

Ok, so I'm using Windows Server 2012 as a Domain Controller.
I've connected two Centos7 clients to the domain via samba.

Authentication works as expected via SSH; however, when attempting
to sudo, pam still asks for a password.

Once you supply the appropriate password, everything works fine,
but I'm looking for a method that would avoid the previously mentioned
password request.

I've been playing around with PAM, but haven't had too much luck.

/etc/pam.d/sudo:

```
#%PAM-1.0
#auth       include      system-auth
auth       required     pam_sss.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session    required     pam_limits.so
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        [default=1 success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        [success=done ignore=ignore default=die] pam_unix.so nullok     try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel        umask=0022
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Kerberos tickets are irrelevant. This is configured in `sudoers`. Of course, it's also potentially dangerous to allow people to do anything without authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not implemented. We (Red Hat IDM team) are thinking about implementing something along the lines of `ksu(1)` functionality for sudo, but currently using your TGT to authenticate to sudo doesn't work, sorry.

If you're using a commercial distribution, I would suggest to file a support case with them..